# Problem with integral of absolute value of a function

Tags: real-analysis

Consider:
 $\int \frac{\sin(n+\frac{1}{2})x}{\sin(\frac{x}{2})} = x + \sum_{k=-n}^{n}\frac{2}{k} \sin(kx)$

from what we do see that $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{\sin(n+\frac{1}{2})x}{\sin(\frac{x}{2})} dx = 2\pi$ for all $n$

now $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|\frac{\sin(n+\frac{1}{2})x}{\sin(\frac{x}{2})}| dx=I_n$(1) does not converge(I mean it holds $\lim_{n\to \infty} I_n = +\infty$) while it shall be $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|\frac{\sin(n+\frac{1}{2})x}{\sin(\frac{x}{2})}| dx = 2\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{\sin(n+\frac{1}{2})x}{\sin(\frac{x}{2})}dx$(and so, this is $2\pi$), which converges.

I need two things: what I did wrong and why this integral(1) diverges?
Who does not believe that (1) does not converge, take wolframalpha and compute with 3,5,7,.... and you will see it grows with n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integrand function is not always positive on $(-\pi,\pi)$.

The $L^1$ norm of the [Dirichlet kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_kernel) is divergent since
$$ \left\|D_n\right\|_1 \geq 4\,\text{Si}(\pi)+\frac{8}{\pi}\log(n)\tag{1}$$
as mentioned by Wikipedia. That inequality is obtained by partitioning $(-\pi,\pi)$ into many sub-intervals whose endpoints are given by roots of the integrand function, then applying a Riemann-sum argument near the origin and Jensen's inequality far from the origin.

$(1)$ is the reason behind [Gibbs' phenomenon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_phenomenon), for instance.

Comment: Thanks, Jack, after 10 minutes of thinking I got that the integrand is not always positive, but thanks anyways!

Comment: can you tell me where I can find the proof for $||D_n||_1 \geq 4Si(\pi) + \frac{8}{\pi} \log(n)$?

Comment: @nikola: you should find it here by a careful search. I added that line on Wikipedia after solving a problem posted on MSE a while ago.

Comment: A proof is given here, too: math.arizona.edu/~friedlan/teach/456/gibbs.pdf